# asp:GridView ImageField DataImageUrlField - specifying multiple fields?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I know I can use `asp:TemplateField` for this, but using the standard asp:BoundField or asp:ImageField in the asp:GridView, is it possible to specify multiple fields and use them in the FormatString field as {0} {1} {2} etc...

For example

```
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ProfileImageId,UserGuid" DataImageUrlFormatString="img-profile.ashx?uid={0}&pid={1}" />
```

I've always pondered on this. This would be much neater than using `asp:TemplateField`

Answer (score 0):

HyperlinkField can use multiple fields to format the url, but you cannot do this with the other *Field columns.

Comment: Thanks, then I gather it can't be done. Silly, be such a useful feature. Wonder why MS did that